# Does it matter whether multiple text objects are selected when doing object to path?

Tags: inkscape, svg

[In this video](https://youtu.be/5kJAKv-8Yp0?list=PL4piInxyechICs3EwT1-fKcQureZ2Ak8v&t=132), instead of selecting all the objects and doing `Object to Path` he selects on text object at a time.

Does it make a difference whether multiple objects vs. just one are selected?

Comment: No. You can make a multiple selection and apply object to path in one go.

Comment: IIUC - If we do it on text objects, then the objects must be ungrouped before certain operations, like cutting using the path, are enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we do the operation on text, then the text must be ungrouped before it can be used in other operations.  See this question for context:

[Cutting a letter from a square Inkscape?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/137520/cutting-a-letter-from-a-square-inkscape)

Also if the letter are not ungrouped, I believe that the ability to use Perspective Envelope with them is affected.